# Why would the following nutritional scenario lead to hunger etc?

Tags: diet, calories, hunger-hungry

Basically if someone had enough calories(but from mostly from carbohydrates and saturated fat only, with a little protein), why would they still feel hungry?  I know lacking adequate protein and fats can lead to health problems but my question is more about why the body would still by hungry despite this diet e.g. Does the body need an minimun amount of calories from protein?

As an example.  Lets say someone needs 1500 callories to maintain body weight/energy. They live only on some chocolate biscuits.  The nutrition for the chocolate biscuit is as follows and they eat 16 buscuits per day:

1 biscuit/16 per day

calories 116 /(so*16)= 1856 calories per day.

saturated fat 6.0g /(so*16)= 48g fat per day.

Carbohydrate 14g/(so*16) = 224g

of which sugars 9g/(so*16) = 114g

protein  1.3g/(so *16) = 10.4

Note that the diet has no polyunsuturated fats or monosaturated fats.  As you can see it exceed the 1500 calories required, uses both carbohydrate and saturated fat and only has 10.4g protein.

I know this diet would cause helth problems however that is not my question.  My questions is:
Why would the body still be hungry despite well exceeding the calories required?
Is it because the body needs a minimum amount of protein(more than 10.4g), the body needs a minimum amount of polyunstaturaed/monosaturated fats etc?  What is the reason?

Thanks

Comment: Because your body is not getting the nutrients it needs. And the body's way of getting you to consume nutrients is by telling you it's hungry? In this case you are technically getting all the *calories* you might need but the body is still lacking (?)

Comment: if larrys answer is correct, could answerer please specify if there would be a minimum amount of protein required or of the hunger would be due only due to vitamins, minerals,or essential fatty acids etc.

Comment: There are way too many variables involved to give you a meaningful answer to that. What's adequate for your body one week may not be the same as the next, never mind all the other thousand variables such as gender, age, fertility status, activity levels, time of year, genes, exercise, health... the list is endless.

Comment: Everyone is always a little unique but there are general guidelines which most people's target amount is near. @james to answer your comment question directly; feeling full has most to do with getting the correct amount of protien, fats, and carbohydrates. Usually in that order. Vitamins are very important but don't really make you feel full.

Answer (score 1):

10 grams protein is way too little. You need about 46-56g of protein per day to feel full.

From Harvard.edu: 
..."protein helps you stay full for longer"...
http://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/extra-protein-is-a-decent-dietary-choice-but-dont-overdo-it-201305016145

From WebMD:
"Adults in the U.S. are encouraged to get 10% to 35% of their day's calories from protein foods. That's about 46 grams of protein for women, and 56 grams of protein for men."
http://www.m.webmd.com/diet/features/how-much-protein